# how to solve importing pandas datareader in jupyter using conda

Tags: python, pandas, python-imaging-library, importerror, eda

I downloaded pandas data reader in Conda using this command   -conda install -c anaconda pandas-data reader

after I downloaded I got this error can you guys tell me how to fix it

ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[3], line 1 ----> 1 import pandas_datareader as pdr  ModuleNotFoundError: No module name

I am expecting how to solve this error
I used instruction from here it showing this error can you tell me how to solve this one

Answer (score 0):

Within Jupyter: Go to "Kernel" > "Restart" to refresh the environment and load new packages.

Use %conda Magic: If the above steps don't work, try installing directly within Jupyter using the %conda magic command:

```
 %conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

Consider conda-forge Channel: If issues persist, try installing from a different channel: `conda install -c conda-forge pandas-datareader`

also Check Case Sensitivity: Make sure you're importing correctly:  `import pandas_datareader as pdr`

Alternative Installation via pip: Run `pip install pandas-datareader` in your terminal or Anaconda Prompt.

Check Installation: Open a terminal or Anaconda Prompt and run

```
conda list
```

Conflicting Packages: In rare cases, conflicts with other packages might occur. Try creating a new environment using `conda create -n myenv pandas-datareader` and running Jupyter Notebook within that environment.

Answer (score 0):

First install using conda,
**conda install pandas-datareader**

if its not successful,

**conda install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git**

Then go to,  Jupyter: Go to **"Kernel" > "Restart"** to refresh the environment and load new packages.
Finally you can import using below command

**import pandas_datareader as pdr**